# Why is a + a = 2a in a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a group A, with an element a. We write that a + a = 2a. This doesn't mean that we've introduced a multiplication operation $*: \mathbb{Z} \times A \rightarrow A$, as far as I can tell. It's just convenient notation. If the group were written multiplicatively, we'd express this as exponentiation.

If we turn A into a vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$, say), we *do* have scalar multiplication, and this multiplication needs to be consistent with addition because of distributivity: a + a = 1a + 1a = (1+1)a = 2a. So a + a = 2a because 1 + 1 = 2 in the field.

So it is just a convention in the group, but once we turn it into a vector space, these definitions of 2a must coincide. This clearly isn't by accident, but I don't see what we enforced in the group to make it so.

**Edit**: I think my confusion was the following. In choosing the convention that a+a+...+a = ka, where you count the a's, we *are* implicitly defining a multiplication with Z, with distributivity, etc. It's just that nobody bothers making it explicit, because it's obvious. Moreover, I didn't realize that there is always a natural mapping from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any field.

Comment: I'll leave this comment here from user David Roberts over at MathOverflow (where I accidentally first posted this):

"Abelian groups are ℤ-modules and vice-versa. And moreover, any ring (eg any field) admits a unique homomorphism from ℤ, and restriction of scalars along this map is what is happening. Also, 'turning an abelian group into a vector space' is done by tensoring with the base field. I suggest asking on math.SE for clarification around this explanation. Good luck!"

Comment: Generally, for a group, if an element $a$ is operated with itself, then the result is written as $a^2$ and not $2a$. We do that in rings, when we have two operations, which we call "addition" and "multiplication" and "addition" of an element $a$ with itself can be written as $2a$. But this has got nothing to do with the multiplication in the ring or from integers. It is just a way of saying that $a$ is added to itself twice. Similarly, in a ring $a^2$ means that $a$ is multiplied with itself twice. Again, it is just a notation!

Comment: Is there any more to this question than the observation that in a vector space $2v=(1+1)v=1v+1v=v+v$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh "Generally, for a group, if an element  is operated with itself, then the result is written as $a^2$" Well, unless we decide to write the group additively, as per my post. It is just notation until we turn it into a vector space, at which point the 2a thus defined must coincide with the 2a given by the vector space structure. Does that clarify the question at all?

Comment: In an additive group the equation $a+a=2a$ chiefly acts as *a definition of $2a$*.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I think there is, though I'd be happy to discover that there's not. Your observation is already described in the OP. In the vector space, if we forget about scalar multiplication/distributivity for a moment, we can use the group structure to define 2a. And then when we remember the vector space structure, we get another definition of 2a (per your observation). These turn out to be the same. This suggests we were always imagining an operation like "*" in the OP, but this is never made explicit.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's fair. Put that way, my question is why does this definition coincide with the definition given by the vector space structure. (See my last comment.)

Comment: I think Hunter's answer gets to that. Do observe that the additive (conventionally thus also abelian) group definition is more general. A part of the problem for you may be that induction does define this "scalar multiplication" for all **integer** multipliers. Group properties suffice to define this. You need associativity to verify a law like $(n+m)a=(na)+(ma)$. You need the group to be abelian for a law like $n(a+b)=(na)+(nb)$ to hold.

Comment: Another way of looking at this connection is to say that when we try to define a vector space structure on an abelian group, we have no choice in the definition of the scalar product as long as the scalar is an integer (or, more generally, an element of the prime field of the field of scalars, if you are familiar with vector spaces over scalars other than real numbers). The additive group structure already forces our hand to this extent.

Comment: Thanks, these comments now make sense to me. A key insight was that there's always a _natural_ map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to the prime field of our scalars. (The other key insight is that we _do_ implicitly introduce the "*" operation in OP in the natural way. I don't know why that confused me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely true that for an abelian group $A$, there is a well-defined map $\mathbb{Z} \times A \to A$ given by

$$
na = a + a + ... + a
$$
where there are $n$ summands if $n$ is positive, and by the negative of this if $n$ is negative. This is a nice exercise in forward-and-backward-induction.

The vector space axioms imply that in particular a vector space $V$ is an abelian group and that the natural map $\mathbb{Z} \times V \to V$ is compatible with the scalar multiplication map.

Comment: Thanks! I was going to ask what happens if our field doesn't contain ℤ (or ℤ/ℤ), but after reading about field characteristics I think that might be resolved. We always get this compatibility guarantee, I guess?

Comment: And if needed, we rename the elements of our field so that they correspond to integers?

Comment: @A_P If you are defining a scalar multiplication with $K$ as a field of scalars, then this observation forces what *the restriction of scalar multiplication to the prime field $F\subseteq K$* looks like. In other words, we have no choice in how to define the scalar multiplication over $F=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Q}$. But if $K$ is a proper extension field of $F$, then there may/will be choices. At that point the question becomes much more subtle (worth another question though actually has been handled already in many interesting cases on our site).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! I had to learn a bit to follow your comment, but I think I see now. It seems that the only prime fields are $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? So if we're trying to extend our abelian group map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to an arbitrary field, there is always a _natural_ way to do so for its prime field.

Comment: @A_P Not all abelian groups can be turned into vector spaces at all (like $\Bbb{Z}_6$). Also, $n$ has to be a prime for a *field* of scalars to be possible. But, for example $V=\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\}$ can be turned into a vector space over the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ in two different ways. If you have not studied field extensions, then this example comes too soon.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I meant $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Can any abelian group of order $p^k$ be turned into a vector space?

Comment: No, @A_P. A field $F$ of order $p^k$ for any positive integer $k$ have the property that $p\cdot 1=1+1+\cdots+1=0$. Therefore the same must hold for any vector space over $F$.

Answer (score 0):

An abelian group is a $\Bbb Z$-module, with the action of $\Bbb Z$ given by $na={\underbrace{a+a+\dots+a}_{n-times}}$.

Any homomorphism of abelian groups is a $\Bbb Z$-module homomorphism.

The categories of abelian groups and of $\Bbb Z$-modules differ in name only.

However, I think, in a general group,  $2a$ does not really make sense; whereas it does in a unital ring, where we have the distributive property.   You can do $a+a$, or $a^2$ in multiplicative notation.